# Pandas Iterate list within a dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe that has a 'books' column with a list of books in each cell. This is an example cell content in the 'books' column:

```
    ["{"book_name":"abc","book_size":"43","requestor":"97457239247","comments":"this is a comment"}",
"{"book_name":"def","book_size":"453","requestor":"27657899462","comments":"this is a comment"}"]
```

I am trying to loop through the cell to find the book that has a specific requester, and then take that entire book object and paste it in a new column.

My code:

```
def find_hipri_book(books):
        for book in books:
            if '27657899462' in book:
                return book
   
    df['hipri_book'] = df['books'].apply(find_hipri_book)
```

I also tried:

```
def find_hipri_book(row):
    for book in row['books']:
        if '27657899462' in book:
            return book

df['hipri_book'] = df.apply(find_hipri_book, axis=1)
```

Both the above give `'float' object is not iterable` error. Please tell me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: did you mean t put the extra `"`? ie One cannot copy paste the bject in python. Probably you meant to have: `[{"book_name":"abc","book_size":"43","requestor":"97457239247","comments":"this is a comment"},
{"book_name":"def","book_size":"453","requestor":"27657899462","comments":"this is a comment"}]`

Comment: Nope! No mistake there. The column data has the extra ". It looks like this: ["{...}", "{...}", "{...}"], except the " inside the curly braces are escaped with a \.

Comment: Then that is not a dictionary. Consider escaping them too, or simply paste `df[columns_you_want].head().to_dict()` otherwise it looks like a dict. Or use single quotes for the outside and not inside

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
a = [{"book_name":"abc","book_size":"43","requestor":"97457239247","comments":"this is a comment"},
{"book_name":"def","book_size":"453","requestor":"27657899462","comments":"this is a comment"}]

pd.DataFrame(a).loc[lambda x:x.requestor == '27657899462'].to_dict('records')

 [{'book_name': 'def',
      'book_size': '453',
      'requestor': '27657899462',
      'comments': 'this is a comment'}]
```

or even:

```
pd.DataFrame(a).query("requestor == '27657899462'").to_dict('records')

[{'book_name': 'def',
  'book_size': '453',
  'requestor': '27657899462',
  'comments': 'this is a comment'}]
```

In case Those are strings rather than dictionaries, yu would have to turn them to dictionary then the rest follows. eg

```
b = ['{"book_name":"abc","book_size":"43","requestor":"97457239247","comments":"this is a comment"}',
'{"book_name":"def","book_size":"453","requestor":"27657899462","comments":"this is a comment"}']

pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(b).apply(eval).tolist()).query("requestor == '27657899462'").to_dict('records')

[{'book_name': 'def',
  'book_size': '453',
  'requestor': '27657899462',
  'comments': 'this is a comment'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this @onyambu. The first solution works for a provided list, but it seemingly does not work for the entire column of the dataframe. I did this:
`a= df['books']
pd.DataFrame(a).loc[lambda x:x.requestor == '27657899462'].to_dict('records')`

This gave the error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'requestor'`

Comment: And applying lambda directly to 'a' give the following error: `'Series' object has no attribute 'requestor'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `'float' object is not iterable` when trying to use function which will iterate in for loop over the list in each cell with apply method and assign it to DataFrame as new column.
I will try to explain my situation and how I solved it, maybe it can help anybody in future.

I worked with DataFrame of many columns, but one of them, let's call it *'ColX'* contains strings separated by comma - f. e. cell contains *'bla,blueh,red,focus'*.
I needed to separate those strings and then iterate over each of them to find their value from source document.

My first attempt was to make it as simple as I can (more steps) and then optimise it (less steps needed):

1.: Created a new column, *'ColX2'*, which contains list of splitted strings

2.: defined function to iterate in for loop over the list items

3.: create another new column, *'ColX_cost'*, where is the sum of each price from source document, by applying defined function on *'ColX2'*

So I did following:

```
df['ColX2'] = df['ColX'].str.split(',')

def find_value_by_itteration(row):
    sum = 0
    for part in row['ColX2']:
        sum += sourcedoc.loc[part, 'price']
    return sum

df['ColX_cost'] = df.apply(find_value_by_itteration, axis=1)
```

I've got the `'float' object is not iterable`.

Took me a lot of time but I don't want to bother you with unsuccesful attempts to solve this so I will describe only the final solution that works.

Decided to simplify and I did not create column with splitted strings (*'ColX2'*), I made my function do this step fo each row.

```
def find_value_by_itteration2(row):
    sum = 0
    parts = row['ColX'].str.split(',')
    for part in parts:
        sum += sourcedoc.loc[part, 'price']
    return sum

df['ColX_cost'] = df.apply(find_value_by_itteration2, axis=1)
```

Using this, I was able to get the result without `'float' object is not iterable`, but infamous pandas `Setting with copy Warning` appeared. My solution to this Warning was to assign the array function creates to new variable, and then assign this array to DataFrame as new column. At the end, the needed part of the code looked:

```
def find_value_by_itteration2(row):
    sum = 0
    parts = row['ColX'].str.split(',')
    for part in parts:
        sum += sourcedoc.loc[part, 'price']
    return sum

arr = df.apply(find_value_by_itteration2, axis=1)
df = df.assign(ColX_cost=arr)
```

Now it works perfectly as I needed, but I am pretty sure someone can find 'python-friendlier' solution.